# New properties to Kinetic objects?

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

How can I add / extend properties to Kinetic objects through a function?

Let me explain further. I can create a new Kinetic object like this

```
var car = new Kinetic.Rect({
width: 15,
height: 10});
```

// and later add custom properties with . notation

`car.brand = "BMW";`

But if I want to make kinectic objects through a function like this

```
var Car1 = new Car(15, 10, "BMW");
var Car2 = new Car(10, 10, "Volvo");

function Car(width, height, brand) {
   this.width = width;
   this.height = height;
   this.brand = brand;
}
```

That will of course not be a kinetic object. But how can I do it? 
Is it possible to extend the base class to be able to hold custom values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be considered relatively ugly out of the box but yes

```
var Car = (function() {
    var _super = Kinetic.Rect.prototype,
        method = Car.prototype = Object.create(_super);

    method.constructor = Car;

    function Car(opts, brand) {
        _super.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    method.drive = function() {
         //lawl
    };

    return Car;
})();

var bmw = new Car({}, "BMW");
var volvo = new Car({}, "Volvo");
```

Ask yourself though if this car *is a* kinetic rect. For me this kind of inheritance doesn't make any sense, I would rather have a car with property like `.boundingBox` referring to a `Rectangle` instance.

---

It becomes a bit cleaner when you extract the common code out somewhere:

```
var oop = {
    inherits: function(Child, Parent) {
        Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
        Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
        return Parent.prototype;
    }
};
```

Then the code will look like

```
var Car = (function() {
    var _super = oop.inherits(Car, Kinetic.Rect);

    function Car(opts, brand) {
        _super.constructor.apply( this, arguments );
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    return Car;
})();
```

Comment: Thanks man. The solution seems a bit "ugly" as you said :-). But is this the way you need to go then? I mean if you want to create hundreds of objects with some extra data you probably want to do that through a function right?

Comment: @Walex I mean this works out of the box without requiring separate "inheritance library"

Comment: @Walex I have added example of a little bit cleaner way when you have separate code